# How to implement strategy pattern in a controller

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I am trying to implement a strategy pattern for the controller component of my program.

I have different view states such as CreateViewState in which you can create items on a blank canvas, so it needs methods like, `createInput()`, `addToModel()` and `stuff`.

Another state that I have is the EditViewState in which you can edit the previously added items. You select an input and then change its color or size or whatever. So methods that controller needs is `selectInputAtLocation()`, or `changeColor(java.awt.Color color)` or `changeSize(int size)`...

The way I go about it is I created an IController interface that has common methods like repOK(), toString() and a couple more like thisWasTheLocation(int x, int y) which the view calls statically to pass the location pressed on the screen to the controller.

However for doing their specific job I don't have a common method that they have. I was thinking about putting a `doStuff(Item item)` method in the interface and then do the controller logic in there so client code can use `IController.getInstance().doStuff(item)` in the entire code. As far as I can predict I will need to cast the controller if I call the specific methods that they have (`changeColor()` for editController, `createInput()` for createController).

If I create a `doStuff()` method in the interface, then I need to implement a lot of if-statements especially for the editController (it has more than 7-8 methods that I did not mention).

How should go about designing this whole system?

P.S: `Controllers` are singletons therefore the `getInstance()`

Comment: I started to try and answer your question again but unfortunately there are too many assumptions I have to make and I don't know what your course is currently trying to teach you, and how far along you are. If you can post a more specific question maybe I can help further. There's nothing wrong with an `if` statement if it works. If you have some working code to post, we can help suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say from your description, but it sounds like you're writing your own MVC framework. Why not use Spring, Struts, or similar? It's not clear how complex your domain model is.

In brief your question *How should go about designing this whole system?* is probably best answered by *Use one of the many existing Java MVC frameworks*

Good design encourages you to move any tricky business logic (`doStuff()`) out of your Controllers and into the Service layer. Your code will be easier to test and not tied to your Controllers.

When you state *So methods that controller needs is selectInputAtLocation(), or changeColor(java.awt.Color color) or changeSize(int size)...* this sounds to me like you're adding complexity where it is not needed.

Using Struts as an example your HTTP Form POST would contain the data that the user has edited and this is available to your Controller in an `ActionForm` bean. You then validate/sanitise this user data before making the decision on which Service method to call (similar to the Strategy pattern you are asking about).

Regarding your Contoller design you could have one have one Controller class per domain model class like this

```
public class ThingDispatchAction extends DispatchActionSupport {

    public ActionForward read( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        // call service layer to read a Thing.java
    }

    public ActionForward edit( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp )
        // call service layer to update a Thing.java
    }

    public ActionForward create( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        // call service layer to create a new Thing.java
    }

    public ActionForward save( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        // call service layer to persist a Thing.java
    }

    public ActionForward delete( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        // call service layer to delete a Thing.java
    }
}
```

Or you could have multiple Controller classes for each domain object, so that there is only one method in each class like the following

```
public class ThingReadAction extends ActionSupport {

    public ActionForward execute( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        // call service layer to read a Thing.java
    }
}

public class ThingDeleteAction extends ActionSupport {

    public ActionForward execute( ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        // call service layer to delete a Thing.java
    }
}

etc ...
```

The chosen MVC framework will have configuration to determine which methods get called, etc.

Comment: This is a homework for a class so I am not using any frameworks such as Spring or Struts.. All I am trying to do is implement a strategy pattern for the controller of the MVC system, which have to do completely different stuff.

Comment: You should update your tags to include "homework" so people are aware of your situation, otherwise we assume you have a "real world" issue.